# modify distances to violate triangle inequality

Tags: algorithm, graph

I would like to test a conjecture that says that the performance of a certain algorithm depends on the degree to which `c` violates the triangle inequality, where `c` is the distance matrix of the instance being solved by the algorithm.

My question is, what is a good way to modify the distance matrix `c` so that I can control the degree to which it violates the triangle inequality?

So far the best I have come up with is something like this: For parameters `p` and `q`, randomly choose `p`% of the elements of `c`, and for each chosen element, multiply it by 1+`u`, where `u` is chosen uniformly from [0,`q`].

I suspect we can do better. Any ideas?

Comment: *"the degree to which c violates the triangle inequality"* The first thing you need to do is mathematically define what that means. And since you haven't revealed the *"certain algorithm"* that you're trying to characterize, there's no way for anyone to help you with that.

Comment: I do not have a precise definition of "degree to which c violates the triangle inequality" -- it is open to interpretation, and that is basically the gist of my question. The conjecture is based on conventional wisdom so has not been defined precisely. As for the algorithm, it's not really relevant to the question, I don't think, but if you think it is: I am trying to test whether off-the-shelf mixed integer programming (MIP) solvers perform worse in solving the uncapacitated fixed-charge location problem (UFLP) when the distance matrix violates the triangle inequality more.

Comment: I'm beginning to understand what you're after. So I'll make an obvious observation. Given a triangle with sides x,y,z, the triangle inequality is not violated unless `z > x+y` or `y > x+z` or `x > y+z`. Therefore, to violate the triangle inequality, the first thing you need to do is choose a side: x, y, or z. Then compute the sum of the other two sides. Multiply the sum by a factor greater than 1, and assign that value to the chosen side. Then lock all three of those entries in the distance matrix, so they aren't subsequently modified.

Comment: I would run a number of tests. For each test I would generate two matrices. One completely random but symmetrical. This will almost certainly violate the triangle inequality. The other the distance matrix based on calculating the distances between random points in n-dimensional space, so it obeys the triangle inequality. Now use a weighted average of these two, using a variety of different weights. Repeat with different base matrices.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks, that is roughly what I had in mind too.

Comment: @mcdowella this is a nice idea. Write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would run a number of tests. For each test I would generate two matrices. One completely random but symmetrical. This will almost certainly violate the triangle inequality. The other the distance matrix based on calculating the distances between random points in n-dimensional space, so it obeys the triangle inequality. Now use a weighted average of these two, using a variety of different weights. Repeat with different base matrices.

Just to add something not in the comment I will note that if you consider any triple of points you can work out the weight, if any, at which the triangle inequality is violated for that triangle, because you are just checking three inequalities where the values are linear plus a constant in the weights. Considering all triples isn't great, since this is O(n^3) in the number of points, but the matrices have O(n^2) elements, so you can always claim its only O(n^1.5) in the amount of input data.